# Position of hole in a semiconductor

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

If there is a vacancy in the valence band does it imply that the hole is in the conduction band? Since the definition of "hole" is -k, -E.

This is the way I interpreted the definition so I wanted to check it.

Comment: No, the electron that occupied that ‘hole’ in the valence band is up in the conduction band.

Comment: What if there was no electron present before. Like p-type semiconductor. In that case will anything be present in the conduction band?

Comment: @MathMarvelian In a P-type semiconductor, there are few electrons in the conduction band. That's why they're called "minority carriers".

Answer (score 0):

When talking about vacancies in either the conduction or valence band, we typically don't worry about assigning labels like "electrons" and "holes". Those labels describe how a state behaves and the states behave differently depending on where they fall in the bands.

Filled states near the bottom of a band behave like a free negatively changed particle, and we call them "electrons". Empty states near the top of a band behave like a free positively changed particle, and we call them "holes".

Vacancies in the valence band are really only possible with any significant probability near the top of the band. A vacancy at the top of the valence band is therefore called a "hole".

Filled and empty states in either band do not, in general, imply anything about what is going on in the other band. Depending on your situation, you might be able to predict something about one band based on what is going on in the other. But there are a lot more variables you will need to introduce before those questions can be answered.